# How do I execute a Python program from within a Flask server?

Tags: python, flask, import

I'm creating a Flask server that will include various Python programs. I want the Administrator to be able to execute them from WITHIN the Flask app. For example, if they click a button, it would execute the Python script.

Currently, the Python file and Flask server execute sequentially when I run the server. As in, the Python file executes first and THEN the Flask server runs (but only AFTER I've terminated the Python program).

For reference, the Python file allows the user to plot points on an image by double clicking on it in a window.

routes.py

```
from app import app, db
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, session
import datasets

app.secret_key = app.config['SECRET_KEY']

/*--------------IRREVEVANT CODE BEGINS---------------*/

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    #Create connection session between SQLAlchemy database and server
    #Select ALL records in tables Lot
    #Store queries in data and push to INDEX template
    data = db.session.execute("SELECT * FROM Lot").fetchall()
    return render_template('index.html', data=data)

@app.route('/info/<lot_id>')
def info(lot_id):
    lotid = lot_id
    #Create connection session between SQLAlchemy database and server
    #Select records in table Spot based on LOT_ID parameter
    #Store queries in data and push to INFO template
    data = db.session.execute("SELECT * FROM Spot WHERE lot_id = :lotid;", {"lotid": lotid}).fetchall()
    return render_template('info.html', data=data)

/*------------IRRELEVANT CODE ENDS--------------*/

@app.route('/test')
def test():
    return datasets.click_and_crop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port='8000', debug=True)
```

datasets.py

```
import cv2
import yaml
import numpy as np

file_path = 'parking_spots.yml'
img = cv2.imread('test1.jpg')
refPt = []
data = []
cropping = False

def yaml_loader(file_path):
    with open(file_path, "r") as file_descr:
        data = yaml.load(file_descr)
        return data

def yaml_dump(file_path, data):
    with open(file_path, "a") as file_descr:
        yaml.dump(data, file_descr)


def click_and_crop(event, x, y, flags, param):
    info = {'id': 0, 'points': []}
    global refPt, cropping

    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDBLCLK:
        refPt.append((x,y))
        cropping = False

    if len(refPt) == 4:
        if data == []:
            if yaml_loader(file_path) != None:
                new_data = len(yaml_loader(file_path))
            else:
                new_data = 0
        else:
           if yaml_loader(file_path) != None:
               new_data = len(data) + len(yaml_loader(file_path))
           else:
               new_data = len(data)

        cv2.line(image, refPt[0], refPt[1], (0, 0, 255), 2)
        cv2.line(image, refPt[1], refPt[2], (0, 0, 255), 2)
        cv2.line(image, refPt[2], refPt[3], (0, 0, 255), 2)
        cv2.line(image, refPt[3], refPt[0], (0, 0, 255), 2)

        corner_1 = list(refPt[2])
        corner_2 = list(refPt[3])
        corner_3 = list(refPt[0])
        corner_4 = list(refPt[1])

        info['points'] = [corner_1, corner_2, corner_3, corner_4]
        info['id'] = new_data + 1
        data.append(info)
        refPt = []

image = cv2.resize(img, None, fx=0.6, fy=0.6)
clone = image.copy()
cv2.namedWindow("Click to mark points")
cv2.imshow("Click to mark points", image)
cv2.setMouseCallback("Click to mark points", click_and_crop)

while True:
    cv2.imshow("Click to mark points", image)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# data list into yaml file
if data != []:
    yaml_dump(file_path, data)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

In this case, I'd expect the Python program to run only when you go the `localhost/test` url. The Flask server would run and then, when a button that takes you to that url is clicked, the Python program runs concurrently until its terminated.

Comment: I started writing an answer but there's too many guesses here. Your immediate problem is `import datasets`. Flask or not, that import executes all of the code of that module on import. You need to look at `if __name__ == '__main__'`

Comment: So, `if __name__ == '__main__'` just puts a damper on the function and prevents it from running on import? That seems to have worked! Thank you.

Comment: Actually, that seems to be a solution for some of the Python files, but not others. I've updated the post above. Am I implementing `if __name__ == '__main__'` correctly?

Answer (score 0):

For anybody that finds themselves here, I figured the solution to this particular problem.

As @roganjosh mentioned, the `import` statement was executing the functions in `datasets` as soon as it was interpreted. To prevent this, you need to include `if __name__ == "__main__"` in the file, which tells the system only execute the specified function when it's NOT called by `import`.

Another "issue" to mention with my `datasets.py` code in particular is that calling `click_and_crop` from within the server didn't work because that function required arguments. I alleviated this by creating a `main()` method and calling that instead. The full solution is as follows:

datasets.py

```
import cv2
import yaml
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('test1.jpg')
image = cv2.resize(img, None, fx=0.6, fy=0.6)
file_path = 'parking_spots.yml'
refPt = []
data = []

def yaml_loader(file_path):
    //contents of function

def yaml_dump(file_path, data):
    //contents of function

def click_and_crop(event, x, y, flags, param):
    //contents of function

def main():
    cropping = False
    clone = image.copy()
    cv2.namedWindow("Click to mark points")
    cv2.imshow("Click to mark points", image)
    cv2.setMouseCallback("Click to mark points", click_and_crop)
    while True:
        cv2.imshow("Click to mark points", image)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

    # data list into yaml file
    if data != []:
        yaml_dump(file_path, data)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    hi = "done"

    return hi

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # stuff only to run when not called via 'import' here
    main()
```

routes.py

```
from app import app, db
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, session
import datasets

app.secret_key = app.config['SECRET_KEY']

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    //Contents of index()

@app.route('/info/<lot_id>')
def info(lot_id):
    //Contents of info()

@app.route('/test')
def test():
    return datasets.main()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port='8000', debug=True)
```

Comment: Thanks @roganjosh for your help